# PHP won't insert data record on my Database

Tags: php

I was trying to insert a messages feature that will insert record inside my database. But for some reason it won't insert my messages and its redirecting me to `home.php` which contains the `login.php` file.

I have three files here:

> 1. home.php
> 2. process.php
> 3. dashboard.php

Now given the three database users, messages, and comment, I need to insert to the database the records of the user who login. For some reason when click on the "Post Message" button it wont insert my message to my database. Any idea?

Here's my `dashboard.php`:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="message">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="message"></textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Post"/></p>
</form>
```

And here's my `process.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'message') {
    //call to function
    post_message(); //use the ACTUAL POST
}

function post_message() { //just a parameter called post
    $_SESSION['errors'] = array();

    if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $_SESSION['errors'][] = "Post Message Can't Be Blank!";
    }

    //now count errors
    if (count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
        die();
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO messages(message, created_at, updated_at)
                  VALUES ('{$_POST['message']}', NOW(), NOW())";

        $result = run_mysql_query($query); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "message successfully posted";
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
        die();
    }
}
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: should this be `mysql_query($query);` instead `run_mysql_query($query);`

Comment: run_mysql_query($query) is a function that I created on my database.php file. and yes I used that function inside it. The problem is just around the process.php file

Comment: add`ob_start();` on top of `process-homepage.php` see if it helps,

Comment: If I'm getting correct according to your question only message not inserted into database, created and updated dates inserted, right?

Comment: All of them. It just redirects me to the homepage.php which contains the login and the registration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82910/discussion-between-shehary-and-rodel-garcia).

Comment: Hello I just message you in chat!

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="process-homepage.php" method="post">
```

the action is set to "process-homepage.php" and your code is in process.php

Can you please change action to process.php and see if it works. If not then set log level to E_ALL and provide error details.

Comment: Sorry. the original file is processs-homepag.php but for demo purpose I set it to process.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the original code of yours to this;

```
<?php session_start();  
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    if (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'message') {
        $Message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[message]);
        if (empty($Message)) {
            $_SESSION['errors'] = "Post Message Can't Be Blank!";
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            die();
        } else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO messages (message, created_at, updated_at)
                      VALUES ('$Message', NOW(), NOW())";
            $result = mysql_query($query); //your run query function changed here but you can also try with run_mysql_query($query);
            $_SESSION['success'] = "message successfully posted"; //made change here from message to success
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            die();
        }
    }
?>
```

Lemme know if this solve the issue, if not we move to chat.

Comment: try to change `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST`, also check your table name `messages` is correct.

Comment: can we go to chat instead mate?

Comment: sure, I'm at chat and also did you include your database file in `process-homepage.php` ?

Comment: Hello @shehary I am on chat/